# Ventilating a shed

Tags: ventilation, shed

I've just bought a house and inherited a shed with power, insulation and opening windows. I intend to use it as a home office.

I'd like to store computer equipment in there, but I'm concerned about moisture. There is evidence of rust on the existing light fittings.

Is better ventilation the answer? If so, should I keep the windows permanently ajar?

Comment: Is the space also climate controlled?  Heating/cooling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enough heat is the first need.

Insulated sheds get cold inside, moisture condenses. Water can even freeze.

As my boss found out with his boat. Insulation just means that cold nights make the interior get progressively colder and not get any thermal gain during the daytime, unless your floor has surface area that transmits enough ground heat. And if you forgot to drain the engine block... Bad things happen despite that insulation.

Once you have heat, a little ventilation as necessary to remove moisture given that it has a good floor that prevents water wicking up into the interior space will help.